# Show DIV on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, css

On `mouseover` can this div be attached to the mouse pointer so that its contents are shown on mouseover?

```
<div id='show' style='display:none;'></div>
```

If so how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div onmousemove="position();" onmouseout="hide();">abc</div>
<div id="tip" style="position: fixed; visibility: hidden;">that's abc!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function position() {
    var d = document.getElementById('tip');
    d.style.visibility = 'visible';
    d.style.left = event.screenX + 'px';
    d.style.top = event.screenY + 'px';
  }
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById('tip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
</script>
```

When the user mouses over the "abc" div, the "that's abc!" div is shown next to the mouse cursor (and follows it).

Comment: k. Can u tell me whtas wrong with this code..
var ele=document.getElementById('show');
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
        ele.width='200px';
        ele.height='30px';
        ele.bgcolor='#a9a9a9';
        ele.color='#fff';
        ele.position='absolute';
        ele.display='block';
        $(window).mouseover(function(event) {
         $("#show").css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX});
        $('#show').height();
        
        });

Comment: event.screenX + 'py' should be event.screenY + 'px'

Comment: @Hulk: The problem with that code is that it's unformatted and impossible to read. More seriously, though, `el` is not defined and you're mixing jQuery and pure javascript code - do you have jQuery loaded? Also, the `height()` call does nothing. @Mic: Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't you use ele.style.width, ele.style.height, etc.? And Hulk, please make a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id='show' onmouseover="this.style.display = 'block';"></div>
```

But for that to work, the div should be visible first. However, if the div is hiddne (display:none) then onmoueever event won't be able to find the div and no event will be triggered on it. Having said that, try this which uses **visibility** property.

```
<div id='show' onmouseover="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"  onmouseout="this.style.visibility = 'hidden';"></div>
```