# div with mouseover does not show as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I looked over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206831/show-div-on-mouseover) page trying to make a simple mouse over menu work (based on the user:sarfraz' answer). I'm not sure if I'm missing the JavaScript but it seems there shouldn't be any. If I load the page I get a `div` with "menu" written into a box and moving the mouse over it keeps it there only once. After the mouse is taken off the `div` box vanishes never to be seen again. I've tried messing with the `visibility` style in the `menu` id, setting it to *visible* or *hidden* and I've also tried setting the style `display:none;` with no luck. I also found this [page](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/14817-javascript-display-a-div-upon-mouse-over) but that one has a permanent list which doesn't vanish with `onmouseout`. Should I just color the `li` tag the same as the background and use that?

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<style>
body
{       
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-color: white;    
}
#container
{       
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto;     
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu
{
    position: absolute;     
    margin: 0 auto;     
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 70%;
    left: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color: purple;

}
</style>
<body>              
    <div id='menu' onMouseOver="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"  onMouseOut="this.style.visibility = 'hidden';">menu</div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he gets `visibility = hidden`, do not be mouseOver, so the code does not run

Alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/V5QrZ/

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    body
    {       
        background-repeat:repeat;
        background-color: white;    
    }
    #container
    {       
        position: relative; 
        margin: 0 auto;     
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menu
    {

        position: absolute;     
        margin: 0 auto;     
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
        top: 70%;
        left: 40%;
        background-color: white;
        border:2px solid;
        border-color: purple;

    }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").mouseover(function(){
        $("#menu").hide()
      });
     $("p").mouseout(function(){
        $("#menu").show()
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
    <div id='menu' >menu</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```